# Show that two sets are equal (involving inequalities)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I couldn't find any examples online of showing 2 sets are equal when the sets involve inequalities and I am struggling on this question:

**A = {x ∈ *R* : x≠0 and (1/x) > 10}.** 
**B =  {x ∈ *R* : 0 < x <10}.**
**Show that A=B by verifying each of the two defining conditions of an equality between sets.**

I know that these two sets are equal and I know you need to show A is a subset of B and vice versa, but I am not sure how to go about showing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To prove that e.g. $B \subseteq A$ you have to consider an $x \in B$ whatever and show that $x \in A$. Consider now $5$ : $5 \in B$ and ...

Answer (score 1):

Two sets are equal if each is a subset of the other.  So for example take an element of $A$, $a$, so that $1/a>10$.  Then show that it is an element of B.  And then do the reverse with an element of $B$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it would be that simple!

Comment: Surely that doesn't show that all elements of A are contained in B though?

Comment: Yes it does, since $a$ is an arbitrary element of $A$.

Comment: oh I thought you meant pick an actual number did you mean to put >10 or >1/10 ?

Comment: Also, this is the part I am stuck on, I'm not sure how to show a is an element of B also.

Answer (score 0):

Let **y** belongs to A.
Then, (1/a)>10.
From this we observe that **a** should be positive, because 10 is positive number.
Thus a>0.
And we easily observe that a<0.1.
Hence  0 < a < 0.1 < 10
Therefore, **a** is an element of B.
Thus A is the subset of B.

Clearly, 2 belongs to B, but 2 doesn't belongs to A.
Thus A is the proper subset of B.

Thus **A not equal to B.**